# Not loaded wordpress database on the live server

Tags: database, wordpress, server

I move my site from localhost to live host server:
1. upload my wordpress website source to server
2. create a database and import localhost database
3. change 'home' and 'siteurl' option to domain name
4. copatible config.php with new live database information

but not load database and show /wp-admin/install.php page!
I try with Duplicator plugin and result is same.
I create another localhost website with this things but work correct!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBv6O.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens if .htaccess file is missing when you uploaded WordPress to live server. Hiddne file may have been missed when you copied your web pages to server.

Permalinks is another root cause of the issue.

Please check if you are able to browse your admin area directly: http://domain.com/wp-login.php. If so, login and go to permalinks settings. Do NOT make any change and click on Save directly.

This will create your .htaccess file and check your site again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I find problem! in the config.php, prefix of tables didn't match with prefix on localhost table. For this reason, the database wasn't loaded